# Dynamic change color of Marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want use different colors of marker to represent different values of some information. Because the value of that information is a successive value, so I need many colors for marker, does anybody know how to set different color of the Marker to implement it? I don't want to use different icon with different color, because it might need to many icon for marker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use StyledMarker or RichMarker from http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries